# What is the Clojure equivalent of Ruby's select?

Tags: ruby, clojure

I want to return a list/collection of all numbers in a range that are a multiple of 3 or 5.

In Ruby, I would do

```
(1..1000).select {|e| e % 3 == 0 || e % 5 == 0}
```

In Clojure, I'm thinking I might do something like...

```
(select (mod 5 ...x?) (range 0 1000))
```

Comment: Fizzbuzz? (and this is all filler...)

Comment: yes sir, project euler to be precise

Comment: always think in terms of map,reduce,filter and so on look at the  http://clojure.org/sequences you will use them a lot in project euler and there is a wiki for project euler solutions in clojure. You can find it here http://clojure-euler.wikispaces.com/.

Comment: nickik: thank you kindly, I will familiarize myself with sequences immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(filter #(or (zero? (mod % 3)) (zero? (mod % 5))) (range 1000))
```

Comment: No problem :)  Project Euler is a great way to learn clojure!

Comment: (zero? (* (mod % 3) (mod % 5)) would be better

Comment: @nickik I guess it depends on what you mean by "better"?  Its more concise, but its also less efficient.  Your code will evaluate the entire form every time.  Using `or` allows the form to short-circuit for numbers divisible by 3.  Also, while your code is more concise, I'm not convinced its also more readable.  Interesting idea though, thanks for the input.

Comment: @dbyrne your right. In production I would do the (or ...) to but in the easy euler stuff i go for the shortes code :)

Comment: That is also a weird math trick. I don't like weird math tricks.

Answer (score 5):

A different way is to generate the solution, rather than to filter for it:

```
(set (concat (range 0 1000 3) (range 0 1000 5)))
```

Comment: You might want to use `(into (sorted-set) ...)` instead of `(set ...)` to preserve the ordering. There's also `sorted-set-by` for user-defined orderings.

Comment: Brilliant! I like it. I wish I could give out more than one correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
(filter #(or (= (mod % 5) 0) (= (mod % 3) 0)) (range 1 100))
```

is the most direct translation.

```
(for [x (range 1 100) :when (or (= (mod x 5) 0) (= (mod x 3) 0))] x)
```

is another way to do it.

Instead of doing (= .. 0), you can use the zero? function instead. Here is the amended solution:

```
(filter #(or (zero? (mod % 5)) (zero? (mod % 3))) (range 1 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this:
http://gist.github.com/456486